# Rear road bike Shimano cassette wobbling during freewheel

Tags: road-bike, shimano, cassette

On my road bike with Shimano stuff the rear cassette with all the cogs wobbles when I free wheel it.

It is very much like this video on youtube, except the bike I own is nowhere near as good or as pricey as the bike (my bike is like a $150-200 bike), and the wobbling on my cassette is much worse (I would describe it as oscillating)

Is this an issue? Is there a way to tighten the cassette so that that it does not wobble?

Comment: I'd start with checking for a bent axle. Also, a 150-200 USD new bike would likely have a freewheel, not a cassette; Freewheels tighten automatically in use, so its highly unlikely that its come loose. More details are necessary/ a video+specs of your bike.

Comment: The hub is bent.  An axle doesn't turn, so you would not see the wobble if it were the axle itself that were bent.

Comment: @Batman Thank you, I will try to get a video up as soon as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not seen a cassette that doesn't do this, IMO they all do it to some degree as the cassettes floats on its bearings unless the pawls are engaged. Some say it's by design perhaps to aid with gear changes etc. 
I used to have £2000 road bike with custom built wheels that used to do the same thing,  it never caused any trouble even after many thousands of miles riding. 
Unless it's causing specific issues I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yeah, I've certainly seen many hubs that do it to modest degree, without any apparent effect on the function of the hub.  Hard to guess how bad the OP's hub is, in this regard.